# How to make an array of Lambda expressions

Tags: c++, arrays, lambda

Is it possible to have an array of Lambda expressions such as here:

```
void somefunction(){
    auto arr = {
        [](){},etc
    }
}
```

I know arrays can not be made of auto so how would I be able to get passed this?

Comment: Array of `std::function`?

Comment: `std::vector<std::function<T>>` or `std::tuple<std::function<T>>` if the types differ.